# SharePoint 2010 Lookup Column - Autofill with the same Item

Tags: 2010, spservices, ajax

I am struggling with some issue. 
I need to automatically fill the value of a field (in Edit or New.aspx)  based on other lookup column.

Now I have list  Lookup with Name and Surname columns

In the second list I have lookup value to this list Name.
If some user will select it the idea is to automatically fill the surname of the same ID.
But also with option to change this field by the users.

Thanks all for help
Dariusz

Comment: I was trying to find something connecting to COM and this task but I could fund anything. If you have some info where to start? Thanks Dariusz

Answer (score 2):

I find it very hard to understand your exact criteria for setting the item in the SELECT box. But you should be able to accomplish this with JQuery in a HTML Form webpart. Here is a pseudo-code example.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
              //Criteria to determine the value to select.
              $('#really-long-guid-id-of-select').val('value-to-select');
     });
```

**EDIT:**
[image]
Looking at the image above, with which you provided me, what you need to do is query List2 for an item where the field "Name" matches the value of the selected item and assign the value of the Surname field to the selected value of the surname select box. Here is a script I use to do something very similar.

```
function setTitle(){
        var reqType = $('#ctl00_m_g_96b4d1be_781c_44eb_941f_c01b7ae00ede_ff61_ctl00_DropDownChoice').val();
        var requestType;
        if(reqType == 'Delete Process')
        {
            requestType = reqType + ' - ';
        }else if(reqType == 'New Process Rev')
        {
            requestType = reqType + ' - ';
        }
        //get teh text of the selected option.
        var processToReplace = $('#ctl00_m_g_96b4d1be_781c_44eb_941f_c01b7ae00ede_ff371_ctl00_Lookup').find('option:selected').text();

        //Use Client Object Model to query the "Process Requests" list for an item with
        //the value above in its title.
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listTitle = "Process Requests";
        list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 

        //Build a CAML query to return only the item with the newest date (top 1)
        var query = '<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'Link_x0020_to_x0020_PDF\' />'
                   +'<Value Type=\'URL\'>'+ processToReplace +'</Value></Contains></Where>'
                   +'<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query>'
                   +'<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /></ViewFields>'
                   +'<RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>';


        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);

        //all the items returned by the query.
        var allItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

        context.load(allItems); 

        context.executeQueryAsync( 
            function(sender, args) {
            //This code is run on success.
                var enumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();

                  while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
                    //Walk through the collection of items (should be only 1)
                    //Set the value of the text box to the value returned by the query.
                    $('#ctl00_m_g_96b4d1be_781c_44eb_941f_c01b7ae00ede_ff11_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(requestType + listItem.get_item('Title'));
                    $('#ctl00_m_g_96b4d1be_781c_44eb_941f_c01b7ae00ede_ff11_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').attr('disabled', true);
                  }
            }, 
            function(sender, args) {alert("error: " + args.get_message());} 
        );

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. I am really newbie in AJAX. If you could give me some tips how to start this :$('#really-long-guid-id-of-select').val('value-to-select');  I know a SQL statements and .NET and of course structure of SharePoint. Thank you very much for help

Comment: Certainly, first JQuery is a JavaScript library. It makes JavaScript much easier to use. You need to add JQuery to your MasterPage. There are a number of resources you can find via Google. Then I suggest a short tutorial on JQuery. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/11/jquery-tutorial-dom-manipulation-and-sorting/

Comment: Once you get an understanding of JQuery view the source of your SharePoint web page and find the <select> tag you wish to set and get the value in the id attribute. You will use that in the JQuery script. Write the if-else logic and set the value of the select tag.

Comment: And just to be clear, I'm talking about the HTML select tag, not a SQL select.

Comment: I have added src to JQuery to my site and also spservices and it seams that works. Running  $(document).ready(function() {
 
        alert("jQuery");
 
    });
give me alert :).  I am not sure <select tag is ID Name ?? I have found it is source of the page but i am not sure which value is it. According to the value that I would like to take is the value from different list (which I am connected via lookupfield now

Comment: Ok perfect, I have found the ID of TextBox and I can set the value to it. Now somehow I need to take the value from other list. Thanks for help Robert. If you have and idea how can i go with it further I will be thankfull:)

Comment: You can use the client object model. The criteria for what to set the select value to was what I was confused about from your question. Just let me know if you would like help with using the COM.

Comment: Hi Robert, Yes if you please could help me with that :) The idea is to take column value from the same Item that now is related. Example: I have lists People(with columns name and surname) and second list Test. In list Test I have lookup to Name. The idea is to take surname(of the same item) when user will select Name. Thank you very much for help !!! :)

Comment: Hi. Could you please give me the direction how I should start to work with COM in AJAX?  Thanks !!:)

Comment: Hi all, I have found how to receive value from External ID based on ID of element of the list. It is described on this page.http://mstechsharing.blogspot.com/2012/03/article-1-basic-sharepoint-2010.html Now the last step that I dont know is how to take ID of element from the Lookup

Comment: Sorry, Dariusz. I lost track of this thread. What do you mean same item? What makes the item in the People list the same as the item in the Test list?

Comment: This is lookup item from different list. So I would like to take the ID of the oryginal Item.

Comment: But how do I know that item 20 in list A needs to have the value of item 8 as the selected value in list B? Are you saying the IDs for each item are the same? List item 1 = List B item 1?

Comment: No I would like to have internal ID of the element which is assigned to Item when it is created. So then I will be able exactly identify which item I want to. Can I put some pictures on this forum then I would show on some picture how I would like this work.

Comment: Sure! Add the picture to your original post using "edit". That's a good idea.

Comment: I tried But unfortunetelyy i dont have enough reputation points ot add image. If you want I can upload it somewhere else.

Comment: Let's go to email. RobertKaucher and gmail is the domain.

Comment: I have the same issue, would you please put the solution