# Autofill column based on document template

Tags: 2010, document-template

I have a column named "Topic" that previously users would have to select prior to saving. However, each topic is based off of the document template they have chosen, so I'd like to make the column autofill based on the document template chosen. Is there a way to do this? Basically, users should hit the drop down arrow below New Document, choose one of the templates I have provided, and then when the document opens up, all of the columns show up as properties for the user to fill out (like Job Code, Date of Discussion, etc.), and Topic is one of them (a dropdown box) that should already be filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using SharePoint metadata in my template to autoselect an area of the document that existed anyway. I found the following resource helpful in figuring this out:

http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2013/11/add-sharepoint-metadata-to-word-documents/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same situation as you are being into.

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31122/sharepoint-2010-lookup-column-autofill-with-the-same-item) will help you move forward

Comment: I don't think this will work for me because I'm not using a form to fill out the columns. The users are selecting this document template I've made using content types, and then the document opens up in Word with the document properties being selectable at the top. They cannot leave this document without first selecting the "Title", so none of it is set in the New form page. Heck, there isn't even one because it's a document library, so I don't think I can use JQuery to solve this unless I'm mistaken.